# How to paste values from multiple inputs through ellipsis?

Tags: r

I'm trying to get all the variables entered through the `...` to be stringed together with a plus in the middle.

```
rhs <- function(...) {
  paste(..., " + ")
}
```

```
rhs("a", "c")
```

For example, the above function should return

```
"a + c"
```

but right now it is returning this:

```
"a c  + "
```

Comment: try `paste(..., sep = " + ")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
rhs <- function(...) {
     lst <- list(...)
     paste0(lst[[1]], " + " , lst[[2]])
 }

rhs("a", "c")
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked Akrun's answer before it was deleted because it also accepted a single variable.

```
rhs <- function(...) {
    do.call(paste, c(list(...), sep = " + "))
 
}
```

Comment: @AndS. has a better solution in the comment to your question:  just use `paste(..., sep = " + ")`.